# How to disable the default behaviour of the backspace button in the browser

Tags: javascript, browser, webkit

I want to create a webpage that listens to keypress event for the body to get what the user is typing including backspace for removing the last letter that the user has typed.

So how can I disable the default behaviour of the backspace button (go back) in the browser to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable backspace with keydown event:

```
$('html').bind('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: And you just prevented anyone from deleting text in any inputs.

Comment: Yes. Question was "How can I disable the default behaviour of the backspace button (go back) in the browser"

Comment: Means user wants to prevent the backsapce button from navigating the page back to the previous page in the history.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will work for you .

```
$(document).unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', function (event) {
var doPrevent = false;
if (event.keyCode === 8) {
    var d = event.srcElement || event.target;
    if ((d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT' && 
         (
             d.type.toUpperCase() === 'TEXT' ||
             d.type.toUpperCase() === 'PASSWORD' || 
             d.type.toUpperCase() === 'FILE' || 
             d.type.toUpperCase() === 'SEARCH' || 
             d.type.toUpperCase() === 'EMAIL' || 
             d.type.toUpperCase() === 'NUMBER' || 
             d.type.toUpperCase() === 'DATE' )
         ) || 
         d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'TEXTAREA') {
        doPrevent = d.readOnly || d.disabled;
    }
    else {
        doPrevent = true;
    }
}

if (doPrevent) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

});